# MariaDB query double data type

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to string query (C++) a data type (double) variable into mariaDB. I'm successfully sending any others variables (i,b and buffer) but double not.

Here is just a part of a code where where I'm trying to send variable hh and others. Any others variables which you can see I'm sending with no problem.

```
double hh= -4.762486e-09;
string query = "INSERT INTO tabulka (n, napatie, prud, cas) VALUES ("+to_string(i)+","+to_string(b)+","+to_string(hh)+",'"+buffer+"')";
```

In database tabulka I'm receiving 0 from variable hh.

TABLE tabulka:

```
MariaDB [hodnoty]> select n, napatie,prud, cas from hodnoty.tabulka;
+------+-----------+------+---------------------+
| n    | napatie   | prud | cas                 |
+------+-----------+------+---------------------+
|    1 |  0.000055 |    0 | 2020-03-03 12:20:09 |
```

```
MariaDB [hodnoty]> SHOW COLUMNS FROM tabulka;
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field   | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| n       | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
| napatie | float     | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
| prud    | double    | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
| cas     | timestamp | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

When i try to insert exact value it is fine:

```
MariaDB [hodnoty]> insert into tabulka (prud) values ('-4.7624816e-09');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)
```

```
MariaDB [hodnoty]> select n, napatie,prud, cas from hodnoty.tabulka;
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| n    | napatie | prud                | cas                 |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| NULL |    NULL | -0.0000000047624816 | 2020-03-03 13:32:44 |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Can you please help me what I'm doing wrong ? Will be happy as an elephant.

Comment: Print out `to_string(hh)`.  I think that will show you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check the query string before executing it.

to_string(double) has precision of 6 decimals. To convert double to string, use ostringstream.

```
  std::ostringstream streamObj;
  streamObj << hh;
  cout << streamObj.str();
```